# Dialogflow/Api.ai Send prompt question using Webhook

Tags: python, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I need to send prompt question with some custom buttons field so that front end developer can show buttons instead of asking just the prompt question.

For example a prompt question will be "where do you want to visit?" and response to this question will be some location like Mumbai or Bangalore (just two of them). So along with the prompt question I need to send two buttons also (using Webhook) whic is not possible now because  prompt question send directly from dialogflow.

So how can I send a prompt question using webhook?

Answer (score 0):

There is something called suggestion chips which i think is the solution you are looking for. Here is the docs for it: https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#suggestion_chips

Answer (score 0):

You can always write it in the custom payload. Please check out following sample code for more understanding. https://dialogflow.com/docs/intents/rich-messages#custom_payload
Replies would be buttons which you would ask frontend to render. Title could be your prompt. Hope this helps. Thanks

```
{
  "facebook": {
    "attachment": {
      "type": 4,
      "payload": {
        "title": "where do you want to visit?",
        "replies": [
          "Mumbai",
          "Pune"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```